# Nuget vs. Web Installer. How is it related to VS 2010 extensions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express, nuget

Does the functionality of these overlap ?  I understand web installer adds pieces to VS2010 and nuget does also..

How are these related to vs2010 extensions that are NOT allowed in vs2010 express. But nuget is allowed in vs2010 express  and that seems to allow extension in the vs2010 express.

Can anyone clear this up for me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nuget is for adding packages or libraries to your current "project" (project meaning general code project not vs proj file). The extension Gallery is designed to extend the functionality of Visual Studio. For instance Nuget Package Manager is in the VS Extension gallery as it extends Visual Studio and adds the ability to add package to your project.

Comment: Ok. So nuget is just for the current project you have loaded in VS ?

Comment: To an extent, its not the strict. NuGet is designed to install code libraries/helpers on any "application/website/etc" while the extension gallery is for installing tooling into Visual Studio.